# slam_toolbox: map - odom transform stuck at time: 0.200

Tags: ros, ros2, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

After migration from Foxy to Galactic I got the following issue:

```
[planner_server-18] [INFO] [1643728496.934987109] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available, tf error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 0.200000 but the earliest data is at time 1643728495.556496, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]
```

The timestamp 0.2000 corresponds to the param `transform_timeout`of the `slam_toolbox`(if I change this param, I get its value displayed in the message instead of the 0.2000) and is not updated, as if the TF was not updated.

This message get printed again and again, preventing my others nodes to works correctly.
Sometime the issue disappears spontaneously after several seconds (but then get other messages).

The TF tree looks like this, the TF seems never updated:
[image: image description]

This is exactly the same issue as described [by this user but on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ROS/comments/qinoxa/slam_toolbox_map_odom_transform_stuck_at_time/).

The TF map<->odom is published by the slam_toolbox in localization mode.

The Tf is regularly published in `/tf` topic and looks like this:

```
transforms:
- header:
    stamp:
      sec: 0
      nanosec: 200000000
    frame_id: map
  child_frame_id: odom
  transform:
    translation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    rotation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
```

What could be the root cause and how to solve this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395470/slam_toolbox:-map---odom-transform-stuck-at-time:-0.200/) by [PatoInso](https://answers.ros.org/users/71833/patoinso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2022-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PatoInso](https://answers.ros.org/users/71833/patoinso/) on 2022-02-02**:
ok, this issue and my [other one](https://answers.ros.org/question/393581/for-nav2-lidar-timestamp-on-the-message-is-earlier-than-all-the-data-in-the-transform-cache/) are somehow linked. Under Galactic, the slam_toolbox sets the timestamp of the TF map-odom with the timestamp of the last laserscan + transform_timeout offset (https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox/blob/f449abf039dd15cd0be719ceeb039533b487329c/src/slam_toolbox_common.cpp#L234). Under Foxy, it was timestamped with now() + transform_timeout offset (https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox/blob/e2f0a71c5475b4e7d32085a18aa89c36f014e28b/src/slam_toolbox_common.cpp#L233).

I replaced in Galactic the laser timestamp by `now()`, and my two issues got resolved... definitively some time issue

**Comment by [PatoInso](https://answers.ros.org/users/71833/patoinso/) on 2022-02-02**:
Also, slam_toolbox misses a lot of laserscan msg. A RCLCPP_INFO in the laser callback shows that sometimes, it is not called for several seconds (up to 10sec), while the scans are published at a solid 20Hz in `/scan` topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, not so sure of the mechanism behind this, but it was related to timestamps issues caused by delays in my laserscan pipeline:

- A first delay introduced by a Message Filter that cached some laserscan message to sync them in my scan merger. So when a new scan was received, the previous scan was typically outputed (so 1 sample of delay)
- The struct of my laser_odometry package was so that the the TF odom <-> base_link was computed and timestamped with the latest laserscan, but was only published 100ms later (a structure with a process() then a spin_some() that processed obsolete data)

Solving this two issues and reducing the delay, so that the timestamp of the TF remains close of now(), solved it for me.

---

Originally posted by [PatoInso](https://answers.ros.org/users/71833/patoinso/) with karma: 109 on 2022-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0